# how to return a string from map using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i have map function which i want to return html string and join to another string and display on modal. i am passing it through function params. The map seems to return array of objects and i am unsure how to convert this to string

```
    let found = [];
found.push({source:'x',destination:'x',protocol:'x',ports:'x'});
found.push({source:'y',destination:'y',protocol:'y',ports:'y'});
let flows = found.map(function(name, index){
    return <li  key={index.toString()} >{name.source.toString()} {name.destination.toString()} {name.protocol.toString()} {name.ports.toString()}</li>
}).reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, ', ', curr]);

showConfirm('',`You are about to approve a local market exemption. Click to confirm! <ul>${flows}</ul>`,()=>{submitApprove(args);self.props.clearModal()},()=>self.props.clearModal(),confirmOptions);
```

**showConfirm open the following modal**

```
    class ModalConfirm extends Component {
        ...

        render() {
            let yesDisabled = false;
            let yesText = 'Yes';
            let noDisabled = false;
            let noText = 'No';

            if (typeof this.props.modals.confirmOptions !== 'undefined') {
                yesDisabled = (typeof this.props.modals.confirmOptions.confirmYesDisabled !== 'undefined') ? this.props.modals.confirmOptions.confirmYesDisabled : false;
                yesText = (typeof this.props.modals.confirmOptions.confirmYesText !== 'undefined') ? this.props.modals.confirmOptions.confirmYesText : 'Yes';
                noDisabled = (typeof this.props.modals.confirmOptions.confirmNoDisabled !== 'undefined') ? this.props.modals.confirmOptions.confirmNoDisabled : false;
                noText = (typeof this.props.modals.confirmOptions.confirmNoText !== 'undefined') ? this.props.modals.confirmOptions.confirmNoText : 'No';
            }

            let bodyWrapper = 'Are you sure you want to confirm?';
            if (typeof this.props.modals.confirmMsg === 'string') {
                if (this.props.modals.confirmMsg.length > 0 || this.props.modals.confirmMsg !== null) {
                   bodyWrapper = Parser(this.props.modals.confirmMsg);
                }
                bodyWrapper = <div className="row-fluid" style={{ wordWrap: 'break-word' }} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(bodyWrapper) }} />;
            }

            return (
                <Modal id="myModalReduxConfirm" className="modal fade" role="dialog" show={this.props.modals.showConfirm}>
                    {this.renderTitle()}
                    <Modal.Body>
                        {bodyWrapper}
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button bsClass="btn btn-success btn-sm" onClick={this.props.handleConfirmYes} disabled={yesDisabled}>{yesText}</Button>
                        <Button bsClass="btn btn-default btn-sm" onClick={this.props.handleConfirmNo} disabled={noDisabled}>{noText}</Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            );
        }
    }
...
```

**result**

```
You are about to approve . Click to confirm! <ul>[object Object],, ,[object Object],, ,[object Object],, ,[object Object],, ,[object Object],, ,[object Object]</ul>
```

UPDATE

i changed to the following now it does not pass string but just displays object.

```
self.props.showConfirm('',() => flows,()=>{submitApprove(args);self.props.clearModal()},()=>self.props.clearModal(),confirmOptions);
```

console.log(this.props.modals.confirmMsg());

**displays**

```
{store: undefined, title: "", body: ƒ, show: true, handleConfirmYes: ƒ, …}body: ƒ ()clearModal: ƒ ()confirmOptions: {confirmYesText: "Confirm", confirmYesDisabled: false, confirmNoText: "Cancel", confirmNoDisabled: false}handleConfirmNo: ƒ ()handleConfirmYes: ƒ ()modals: {showConfirm: true, confirmTitle: "", confirmMsg: ƒ, handleConfirmYes: ƒ, handleConfirmNo: ƒ, …}show: truestore: undefinedtitle: ""__proto__: Object
main.bundle.js:200439 
[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]
```

You can see the body shows `f` and when i log it, it does not interpret the object

Comment: Please post a **complete** example. For example, be sure to include a variable declaration for `found` and any other variables used. Note that in your current implementation, the invocation of `map()` will return an array of React components, not a string.

Comment: i have added variables content

Answer (score 2):

Your JSX elements cannot be rendered in arrays that mixes them with strings. And using reduce with JSX will often lead to headaches.

A quick solution to your problem would be to map your array directly and check if the element is not the last of the array to add the `,` :

```js
const found = [
    {
        name: {
            source: "eirglerk",
            destination: "zlekjrnzi"
        }
    },
    {
        name: {
            source: "lkcyukyuk",
            destination: "uylcl"
        }
    },
    {
        name: {
            source: "trutrurt",
            destination: "culcul"
        }
    }
]

const App = props => (
    <p>
        You are about to approve . Click to confirm!
        <ul>
            {found.map(({ name, index }, i) => 
                <li key={index}> {name.source} {name.destination} {name.protocol} {name.ports}{i !== found.length - 1 && ','}</li>
            )}
        </ul>
    </p>
)


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

Or by keeping your code, you can do the following if you encapsulter the comma into a JSX element :

```js
const found = [
    {
        name: {
            source: "eirglerk",
            destination: "zlekjrnzi"
        }
    },
    {
        name: {
            source: "lkcyukyuk",
            destination: "uylcl"
        }
    },
    {
        name: {
            source: "trutrurt",
            destination: "culcul"
        }
    }
]

const App = props => (
    <p>
        You are about to approve . Click to confirm!
        <ul>
            {found
                .map(({ name, index }) => <li key={index}> {name.source} {name.destination} {name.protocol} {name.ports}</li>)
                .reduce((prev, elem) => [prev, <span>,</span>, elem])}
        </ul>
    </p>
)


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

You will need to ass some CSS to keep your commas inline though

Comment: the problem with this one is i cant pass the `flows` to the function i am trying to make use of a reusable modal

Answer (score 0):

Assume if I have found1, found2 and found3, based on the clicked button change I switch and map to loop the structure?

```
const found1 = [
{
    name: {
        source: "eirglerk",
        destination: "zlekjrnzi"
    }
},
{
    name: {
        source: "lkcyukyuk",
        destination: "uylcl"
    }
},
{
    name: {
        source: "trutrurt",
        destination: "culcul"
    }
}
]

const found2 = [
    {
        name: {
            source: "eirglerk",
            destination: "zlekjrnzi"
        }
    },
    {
        name: {
            source: "lkcyukyuk",
            destination: "uylcl"
        }
    },
    {
        name: {
            source: "trutrurt",
            destination: "culcul"
        }
    }
]

var foundtype = "found1"

JSON.foundtype.map(() => { 
//Load found1 data
}
```

Comment: Your current question is quite ambiguous, please refine it to make it more concrete. Also, if you add your desired result and the things you tried already people are able to help you faster.